# Dynamic table cell height in XSL-FO?

Tags: xsl-fo

I'm generating a table in XSL-FO and my content is a text that can be large. Is there any way to resize the column height? I´m using XSLT to generate the XSL-FO. 
I tried:

```
<fo:block-container font-family="Times New Roman"height="7.14mm" 
                    overflow="hidden">
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code is missing a space between the font family and height property. You should also put an fo:block inside your container. The following works for me and fixes the height of my block, hiding overflowing text:

```
...
<fo:table-cell>
<fo:block-container font-family="Times New Roman" height="7.14mm" 
                overflow="hidden"> 
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="fieldWithLongText" />
    </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
</fo:table-cell>
...
```